# insertion sort...tweaks to improve?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

i know insertion sort isn't that great...but even still...what are two more simple improvements that could be made to the sort below?

```
public static void insertion_sort_with_moves(int[] arr){
    for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++){
        int v = arr[i-1];
        int j = i-1;
        for (/*declared j outside loop*/; j > 0; j--) {
            //compswap(a[j-1], a[j]);
            if (v < arr[j-1]) arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            else break;
        }
        arr[j] = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Proving its correctness is very useful. So is making it generic.

Comment: Why 2 improvements?  Why not 1 or 3?

Comment: There is no reason to declare j outside the for; it could be done like 'for (int j = i - 1; …)' instead.

Comment: Because it's Java, any variables that are not going to change after being declared in the loop could be declared `final`. This allows the compiler to make certain optimizations it wouldn't be able to otherwise.

Comment: No, it's supplemental questions from our lecture. And I have no idea how to make it 'faster'. Supposedly, there are two simple improvements we can make...involving terminating the inner loop early knowing that a good bit of the list is already sorted.

Comment: Seems like it's already been done...either that or I'm just really lost.

Comment: First of all why in question you're asking about "improvements" and only then in comments mention specifics - speed? And in terms of readability I'd make it while with 2 conditions instead of for, so no inner if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few micro-optimizations are:

1,2,3)

```
    int len = arr.length; 
...

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
            int v = arr[i];
            int j = i;
```

Saves you from computing i-1 two times and ++i is faster than i++.
Not sure about the length thing (could save the offset addition when accessing a class member).

4,5)

```
for (/*declared j outside loop*/; j != 0; --j) {
```

j!=0 should be faster than j>0 (really don't expect much) and --j is faster than j--.

Well most of them may be platform dependent and may make no difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is that you could use a binary search on the sorted part of array to find where it belongs and use System.arraycopy to move the subarray over by one more efficiently than iterating through. You're still O(n^2) but on large arrays it will be a small improvement.

Another is to declare any variables that won't change as final to allow for compiler optimization (as I noted in my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

*Updated based on comments:*

Some improvements to help readability:

1. Don't use underscores in your method names.  Use camel case instead.
2. Consider curly braces around if/else statements to make them easier to read or at least put in more new lines.
3. Remove code that is commented it out if it is not needed.
4. Consider removing comments that explain "what" instead of "why".
5. Try to avoid one character variables especially when you have several in the same scope.
6. You might be able to make use of a for each loop rather than having to declare and access the v variable. (Would still need the current index, but other changes might allow this)

Comment: Does that really improve the sort itself? I'm pretty sure he's looking for code improvements, even if it doesn't explicitly say that.

Comment: @glowcoder, yes the more readable it is the more potential for bugs to be found and improvements to be identified.

Comment: Extra curly braces are not an improvement. Proper indentation is.

Comment: @jzd Those are a matter of style, not performance. In fact, it is very common to have a rule that says "If statements must have curly braces, even for one liners, unless the entire statement is on the same line as the if statement." And while almost every Java developer uses camelCase instead of underscores, has 0 impact on finding bugs in the method.

Comment: Also, I should point out i'm not the downvoter. I **do** find your statements potentially useful, just not to answering the question at hand :-)

Comment: @glowcoder, I would have to disagree, if you are putting code in front of a large audience or writing code that will be maintained by others, then it is important to follow convention and make the code readable. This way, when someone else is following the code and they see `Group` as opposed to `group` they can assume it is a class not a variable.

Comment: @jzd Then we'll just have to agree to disagree. Again, I think they're good suggestions, but I don't feel they're answers to the question.

Comment: @glowcoder, I have updated my answer to specify that the improvements are focused on readability not on speed improvements and increased the list or recommendations.